# Why does data-table table last header not align with last column?

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10, zurb-foundation-5

I created a table with DataTable library (that is using foundation-zurb 5.5.3), Per the below image I'm seeing both in Chrome as in IE 11 that the most right column header [image: the most right column header]  does not align with the other rows when you first open up the page. The actual webpage is http://iprobesolutions.com/learn/wireless-conference-system-comparison. However if I open devtools to try and inspect the code the issue dissappears! When I refresh with CTRL+ F5 it however reappears.

The issue does not appear when I create this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/setbon/x75o53ck/

Below is just a small part of the code pasted. I'd really appreciate if you could look at the webpage since this is where the issue is displayed...perhaps a bug in IE and Chrome ?

```
<table id="example" class="display nowrap table1 compact">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are loading the Datatables FixedHeader code. I don't see how or if you are using it but its not compatible with scrollX and scrollY:
https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/

Try removing either FixHeader or the scrolling options.

Comment: Per our convo at datatables forum...many tx for ur help Kevin!

Answer (score 0):

Usually these type of issues occur when table is hidden when initialized and then becomes visible in a tab, modal dialog, etc.

In most cases the solution is to call
[`columns.adjust()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()) to recalculate column widths once table becomes visible.

```
table.columns.adjust();
```

When I ran the code above after your table is initialized, the issue disappears.

I cannot explain why this issue occurs with your table. I'm not familiar with Foundation framework, but I don't think you have to call `foundation()` when initializing the table.

See [jQuery DataTables: Column width issues with Bootstrap tabs](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs/) for more information, examples and details.

Comment: Thank you very much for response. I placed your code as follows but nothing happens...what is the correct location where I should paste the line of code please ?                                           
         table.buttons().container()
        .appendTo( '#example_wrapper .small-6.columns:eq(0)' );
        table.columns.adjust().draw();

      }).foundation();
      </script>

Comment: I placed your line of code into a fiddle where I updated the JS code: http://jsfiddle.net/setbon/m1Lg8h9f/

Comment: when you have a chance, I'd really appreciate if you could show me in the filddle where to place your code.